# PHP doesn't echo the correct variable from array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, echo

So,I send an array of inputs:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Question" name="question[]"  value="" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Question" name="question[]"  value="" />
```

with this Jquery code:

```
    $.post("function.php",{Question:$("[name^='question']").serialize()},function(data){
    $("#construct").append(data);
    alert('done');
});
```

but when I try to `echo` the variables of array it prints incorrect
PHP(function.php):

```
$Question=htmlentities($_POST['Question'],ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
echo $Question[0]."<br>";
echo $Question[1]."<br>";
```

Now imagine that we enter "Hello" and "Bye" in the input So it should return "Hello" and "Bye" but it returns "q" and "u" instead.

The `var_dump` out put is:

> string(39) "question%5B%5D=Hello&question%5B%5D=Bye"

**Edit 1**

if I use `.serialize()` I always get "q" and "u" but if I use `.val()` I get the first and second letter of each word

**Edit 2**

I even tried the PHP code without `htmlentities()` but the result is the same as before.

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump(($_POST['Question']);` in your question

Comment: @JohnConde I edited my post with `var_dump` output

Comment: Why am I getting down-vote?????

Answer (score 1):

You serialized your input in JavaScript so the input coming in PHP is a string, not an array. So you need to decode it into an array. Using JSON is a good approach.

**EXAMPLE** for the lazy:

JavaScript

```
var normalArray = $('#FormID').serializeArray();
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(normalArray);
$.post("function.php",{
  data: jsonArray
});
```

PHP

```
$normalArray = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

This example is not tested, but it should work in general.

Comment: So,What can I use instead of `.serialize()`??

Comment: use `JSON.stringify( my_array )` in javascript my friend. And in PHP you do `json_decode($_POST['question'], true)`.

Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937144/sending-javascript-object-to-php-via-ajax
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: So you stringify your data in JavaScript to Json, send it to PHP, decode the Json into an array, go mark P. jensen's anwser as a good anwser. And he saw that everything was well.

Comment: Dude, don't be lazy. If you don't learn it by researching and writing it yourself, you will never remember it. Use the links I gave you.

Comment: Can I use `JSON.stringify()` in Jquery.post??

Comment: Made an example, try to adopt it into your own project.

Comment: you know,my form includes several inputs and I want to send the inputs with name question into `function.php`. I hope you understand my purpose.So that I think it isn't a good way to send the whole form to `function.php`. btw I edited my post.Please take a look at it again

Comment: Selectors should work in jQuery aswell `$(':input')` and such. Does not have the anwser right now, will maybe anwser later.